Is every non deductive argument technically a logical fallacy?
As per the IEP, a valid deductive argument is one whose logical structure or form is such that if the premises are true, the conclusion must be true.
For any other kind of argument, this would imply that the conclusion is not necessarily true if the premises are true. But is this not the equivalent of stating that the conclusion is not implied by the premises? If so, would this be a case of a non sequitur fallacy which states, as per the Oxford dictionary:

a conclusion or statement that does not logically follow from the previous argument or statement


Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

"Formal" fallacies are typically only identified in relation to deductive arguments.
A deductive argument suffers from the formal fallacy of non sequitur if and only if the argument is invalid: the conclusion is not necessitated by the premises. Depending on usage, non sequitur can encompass all formal fallacies (any kind of invalidity), or only those invalid arguments that don't fall into other named fallacies.
Other kinds of argument (e.g. inductive or abductive) don't even purport to necessitate their conclusions. It is not a fallacy for a non-deductive argument to be deductively invalid.
If you want to call any argument a non sequitur whose conclusion does not follow from the premises, even inductive or abductive arguments that don't even claim to necessitate their conclusions, then sure, you can do that. You will just need to be clear that's what you mean, because many do not understand the term to apply in that domain.

I have no idea what the question author means by "technically a logical fallacy" or what the commenter means by "fallacious in principle" as distinct from simply "a fallacy." I am not saying fallacies only apply to deductive arguments. There are many fallacies that can be committed within a non-deductive argument. I'm saying that the conclusion not being necessitated by the premises is expected in non-deductive arguments.

I guess the question would then be: is an inductive or abductive argument fallacious in principle if the conclusion does not follow from its premises?

I am asking if inductive arguments commit any logical fallacies. If the response is that inductive arguments don't claim to necessitate their conclusions, why are they not all committing a non sequitor fallacy? Saying that fallacies only apply to deductive arguments, even if this is true in how we decide to categorize fallacies, seems like special pleading @Lowri

@Syed: You can define the word "fallacy" such that the answer is yes, and you can define it such that the answer is no. Because English is not French, neither of these definitions has a significantly greater claim to being correct. IMHO the word "fallacy" is only useful in simple cases where some argument is obviously incorrect and it merely provides vocabulary for stating that fact. In other contexts, it is more productive to focus on the arguments being made and not on whether some arbitrary magic word applies to them.

@Kevin I completely agree with the latter part of your comment and that is exactly why it seems to be a semantic side point when people keep referring to how formal fallacies may only apply to deductive arguments (although my question doesn’t use the phrase “formal fallacy” in the first place).

@Syed: If you agree with me, then I must confess that I do not understand why you asked the question in the first place. It does not appear to have a definite, correct answer, nor does there appear to be much room for further exposition of the subject matter in the answers. I had been giving you the benefit of the doubt rather than voting to close, but if you asked the question knowing that it had no answer, I'm not sure I can continue to extend that benefit in good faith.

@Syed: Please do not impugn the motives of other users. I don't know or care what argument you are having with other users on this site. I already linked to the help center, which explains why questions of this nature are not allowed on Stack Exchange. If you disagree with that rule, I would suggest taking this content to Quora or another site where such discussions are encouraged.

@Syed: It is not my responsibility to explain or justify the rules to you. I have linked you to the rule which applies, and your disagreement with that rule is between you and Stack Exchange. Since this discussion is obviously non-productive, I will not respond again.

Is every nondeductive argument technically a logical fallacy?
No. I offer this answer because of the specialized nature of an inductive argument.
Suppose you encountered this argument: I have seen 100 consecutive swans that were white: therefore all swans are white.
Such an argument is simple enumeration, which proves nothing. The fallacy is hasty generalization.
The conclusion reached by induction is the
contrapositive of the conclusion reached by deduction. Deductive reasoning reaches its conclusion by first defining an area and then
determining whether an observation fits inside it. If there is a fit, then the conclusion is valid. So:
All swans are white; this bird is a swan; thus this bird is white.
Induction approaches its conclusion from the opposite direction. Induction defines an
area then determines whether an observation falls outside it. The syllogism becomes: All non-
white things are not swans; This object is not white; thus this object is not a swan.
The inductive process identifies the line that divides observations that falsify a hypothesis from the observations that are inconsistent with it. Start with the following hypothesis: “If a bird is a swan, then it is white.” The observation of a black swan lies on the falsification side of the line, as would the sighting of a green or red swan. The observation of a white swan appears on the consistency side of the line. So far, these examples are easy.
But what about a gray swan? Gray is not white, so identifying such a sighting as a falsifier remains fairly simple. But what happens as the gray coloration becomes lighter and lighter? As the color lightens on each successive observation, the judgment between white and non-white becomes more difficult. Most importantly for the hypothesis, the exact location of the line of falsification becomes more clear.
This progression of increasingly closer judgments reflects the nature of the line of falsification. The line serves a function similar to that of a limit in mathematics. The line of falsification is a boundary which may be approached, but might never be reached. The precise path of the line will never be known because it is impossible to know that one hundred percent of all qualifying events have been observed.
The result of this process of exclusion is an estimate of the final image described by the hypothesis. This inductive estimate does not have the satisfying certainty of a deductive conclusion, but it is no less valid.

But then the second argument isn't really inductive if the conclusion is within the observed facts, and so you haven't done anything to establish that non deductive arguments aren't fallacies

@Syed. I’ll try again. Thanks.

@Syed. How about that?

We could see Bayesian-style reasoning as a form of deduction with evidence:
Classical Logic (where P, L, E, Q are propositions)

If P and L and E then Q

Bayesian reasoning

If we accept prior (P) and likelihood model (L) and agree we have evidence (E) then E makes it more likely that Q

Here we can formally associate "True" with "Is made more probable given E", so we can convert inductive/observational logic to deductive.
We can also go with "True" = "More likely than not" (again, formally) if we are talking more about the theory than the evidence.
That's about as close as I can get to making induction like deduction.

The question is not whether induction can be made like deduction. The question is whether induction, and abduction, in general is fallacious in the sense that the conclusions do not follow from the premises

@Syed if you see above,  there are statements that are deductively valid despite being inductive.

I see. Well then that just seems to be a trick since it would beg the question of how one can justify how probable H is given E, and whether the notion of a probability of H can be given meaning or be justified objectively in the first place @Annika

@Syed " beg the question of how one can justify how probable H is given E" no, those are antecedents just like in classical logic. The probability of H can be given modal semantics and justified from historical values.

what does “justified from historical values” mean? Probabilities suffer from a reference class problem, and the notion of logical probability that you seem to refer to is very contentious.

@Syed by agreeing in a prior and likelihood you implicitly pick a reference class. It all boils down to if a then b

that would still then beg the question of why we should agree on that particular prior and likelihood. This seems to be a trick in that it’s merely moving the justification of an inductive argument to the justification of a particular prior and likelihood @Annika

Let us continue this discussion in chat.


A fallacy is an argument that contains an error in reasoning, an error in applying the accepted rules for its type of argument, thereby making the argument invalid or misleading.
There are non-deductive arguments that have as purpose to strengthen the belief in some thesis; for instance, arguments that simply enumerate pieces of evidence to adopt a thesis or to keep believing in it. An enumeration of pieces of evidence without any pretense of presenting a deductive proof does not contain an error in reasoning and does not apply accepted rules for its type incorrectly.
Therefore, not all non-deductive arguments are fallacies.

